# Existence and uniqueness of limit cycle for $r' = μr(1-g(r^2)), \text{and} θ' = p(r^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

**Exercise :**

> Consider the dynamical system :
>   $$r' = μr(1-g(r^2))$$
>   $$θ' = p(r^2)$$
>   where $μ>0$ is a constant and $g,p: \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R \space$ are smooth functions with $p(1) > 0$ and $g(1) = 1$. Show the existence of a limit cycle. Is the limit cycle unique ?

**Attempt :**

So, first of all, we have to check the sign of $r'$. Since $μ>0$, we observe that the points $r=0$ and $r=1$ are stationary points, since $g(1) = 1$. In previous cases, one would have to study the changes of the  sign of $r'$ depending on $r$ and would then fix an one-dimension phase portrait with arrows denoting the monotonic domains. If the arrows would "converge" $(\rightarrow \space \leftarrow$) around an equilibria, then this is enough to show that a unique cycle exists.

In this particular case though, I am unable to conduct such a result, since we are not sure of the sign of the expression $(1-g(r^2))$ but we only know that it has a zero point at $r=1$.

I'm pretty sure there's another way around, especially since we're given that $p(1) >0$ which I am not sure where to use yet (I guess it shows a clockwise "movement" of the phase portrait).

I would appreciate any hints or help !

Comment: As the problem stands, we need more information about $g$. Take the simple counter example $g(r^2) = 1$ and $p(r^2) = r^2$. Then the orbit of every point is a counter-clockwise circle of fixed radius, and the cycle of $r=1$ doesn't attract any points (either in forward or reverse time!). This is also true for the infinitely many limit cycles present in this example

Comment: If we fix by adding hypotheses on $g$, then recall that a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle doesn't require the limiting behavior to occur with forward time! In effect, we need just one arrow that points towards or away from $r=1$. The smoothness of $p$ and $p(r) =1$ gives that the $\omega_\pm$ set of a nearby point has to get "sucked into the rotation", rather than just asymptotically approaching a single point on the circle $r=1$.